# is there a way to do conditional rendering on nav-bar to show user-name and logout link and when logout show login and register link in next.js??

Tags: next.js

when login in, the nav-bar shows hello{user-name} and the logout link which is what i want, and when i logout the nav-bar shows hello with no name and logout link instead of login and register link.
i'm new to react and next ,where am i going wrong?
`import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

```
const TopNavBar = ({ user }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link href="#">
            <a className="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
          </Link>
          <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="/">
                <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
                  Home
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="/about">
                <a className="nav-link">About</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="/contact">
                <a className="nav-link">Contact</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="/ninjas">
                <a className="nav-link">Ninja</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="/demos">
                <a className="nav-link">Demos</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul className="navbar-nav me-2 mb-2">
            {!user && (
              <React.Fragment>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link href="/auth/register">
                    <a className="nav-link">Register</a>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link href="/auth/login">
                    <a className="nav-link">Login</a>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
            {user && (
              <React.Fragment>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link href="#">
                    <a className="nav-link">Hello {user.name}</a>
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link href="/auth/logout">
                    <a className="nav-link">Logout</a>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TopNavBar;`
```

Comment: It might help if you also share what you are using for authentication. If you haven't yet set up authentication then you might want to check out next-auth 
https://next-auth.js.org/

Comment: How are you handling authentication? Where does `user` come from?